# I want to print a unicode box in my recycling waste algorithm

Tags: java, unicode

I am having trouble with creating a box. This is the homework assignment I am having trouble with. This is what I am getting with my code so far:

```
System.out.println("\t\t\tAnnual\sWaste\sCharges");
        int bucky[]= {32, 12, 18, 54, 2};
        
        System.out.printf("\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503\r\u2503");

        
        System.out.println("\tGreen Clean recycling waste" + 0f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tGreen Clean general waste" + 0.21f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tGreen Clean organic waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tGreen Clean glass waste" + 0.15f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tCountry Collect general waste" + 0.14f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tCountry Collect recycling waste" + 0.14f + "year");               
        System.out.println("\tCountry Collect organic waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tCountry Collect glass waste" + 0.12f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tEnviro general waste " + 0.30f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tEnviro recycling waste" + 0f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tEnviro organic waste" + 0f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tEnviro glass waste" + 0f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tWaste Away general waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tWaste Away recycling waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tWaste Away organic waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        System.out.println("\tWaste Away glass waste" + 0.10f + "year");
        
        
        System.out.printf("\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501\u2501");
        
        
    }
}
```

Can anybody help with this as soon as possible? I am meant to be designing this box in Unicode in Java as well, thank you. ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdKoa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGx6A.jpg)

I am trying to work on building a chart out of Unicode for my Java class.

Comment: Hint: `System.out.println("\u2503    Some text    \u2503");`

Comment: It's really important to include properly-formatted text for all code/data/errors/output. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.